# Java compress Object or List<double[]>

Tags: java, compression

I have an object that has the following structure:

```
public class CompressionWrapper implements Serializable {
    private List<double[]> blocks;
    private int height;
    private int width;

    constructor, setters and getters...
}
```

each double array in `blocks` is 64 elements long, and I need to compress this into a file. Which library would be the best for this type of compression?

I have tried using `GZIPOutputStream` from `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream`, but that actually increases the size of the input file from 490KB to 1011KB.

My compression method looks like this:

```
public static void compress(CompressionWrapper wrapper, String path) throws IOException {
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        GZIPOutputStream gzipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(wrapper);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

`$ gzip -l out.bin`

```
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
             253314          4293110279 100.0% out.bin
```

Changing from `double` to `float` made a significant difference, should have thought of that myself. Also, upping the compression threshold also made a difference.

Comment: How are you serializing the object? If you're printing out decimal representations of doubles, then that will significantly expand the data, making the job of the compressor much harder. Also why do you expect your data to be compressible? Is there redundancy in the doubles? Is it a time series with adjacent values that are close to each other? Can you reduce the precision of the data in the doubles without losing the accuracy of the information?

Comment: @MarkAdler not seralizing it in any special way, just initialized a new object and tried to compress it. I expect the data to be either compressed, or in the worst case a bit worse than the current data, I am using discrete haar wavelet transformation on an image, which should also contain some consecutive zeros. Also, I just tried converting to float, and that did significantly help, reduced from 1011KB to 616KB, but it is still higher than 490KB. Float should not have significant information loss in my case

Comment: Can you do a `gzip -l` on the output file and share the result?

Comment: @MarkAdler I have updated the question, I think it's working as it should now. I will play around a bit, when i get the time tomorrow

Comment: Wait, that size is way bigger than a megabyte. It's gigabytes. At that point, the output of `gzip -l` is not reliable.